# How to run multiple macro instances using Remote Dekstop Connection and Amazon AWS EC2

Tags: macros, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, remote-desktop

I am trying to to run multiple Remote Desktop connection instances with Amazon's AWS EC2 and keep a macro file running on each instance via Macro Express (installed separately on each node), but each time I minimize an instance, the the mouse movement of that macro freezes and the process is suspended.  Since these macros that I am running rely on specific mouse positioning/movement, is there any way of keeping them running on each instance after I minimize?

Thanks a bunch,
Jake

Answer (score 0):

If you change screen with keyboard than mouse position on previous server will not change.
Not quite what you asked for, but might be helpful enough:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>←</kbd> - switches you to the host computer

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>→</kbd> - switches you back to the remote computer

Also can help:

[Keyboard Shortcuts in Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) for Navigation](http://www.mydigitallife.info/keyboard-shortcuts-in-remote-desktop-connection-rdc-for-navigation/)